# PHP numbers and delimiter

Tags: php

I have this number `"150 000"` how could I print it like this:
no thousand delimiter and `"."` as decimal delimiter?

I tired Str_replace but it did not work, Is there is any simple code to do it ?

Comment: Give more example's of expected results ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.number-format.php)

**Example:**

```
 echo number_format("150000", 2, ',', ' ');
```

Output:

```
150 000,00
```

**Example #2:**

```
  echo number_format("150000", 2, ',', '');
```

Output

```
150000,00
```

Answer (score 0):

One aproach could be this:

```
<?php
$myNumber = "150 000";
$myNumber = filter_var($myNumber, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo printf('%1$f', $myNumber);
```

Answer (score -1):

First remove spaces with str_replace(), then format number with number_format():

```
$num = '150 000';
echo number_format( str_replace(' ', '', $num), 2, '.', '' );
```